# How to print dropdown values of a select tag using javascript?

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsp

I'm having a dropdown for selecting cities of Tamil Nadu.
All the cities are in an array list and using a for loop, I am iterating the values and writing using document.write but still I'm not getting the values printed in dropdown.

```
<select>
   <script>
      document.writeln('&ltoption value="chennai">');
   </script>
</select>
```

How to get the dropdown values printed now?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you explain it clearly???

Comment: Thanks for response! I got to print the dropdown values of a select elemt using java script's document.writeln(""); how to do that?

Comment: WHy dont you use the php snippet for this drop down box??

Comment: how to use it?Im not aware of that...Also i need this in my jsp file....

Comment: Lemme explain u the scenario clearly...in my registartion form i have a dropdown for state and city. I'm having a list of indian states and cities. using a for loop in javascript i can iterate thru the list. now i must write the list elements into a select element so that they might appear in the drop down list....

Comment: Why don't you do this with server-side code?

Comment: your question doesn't explain things enough, please modify/update your question with appropriate example and text.

Comment: You've tagged this jquery - is it safe to assume that you are using jquery in the project you're working on (makes the answer easier)?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using jquery :

Assuming your HTML is similar to this

```
<SELECT NAME="mylist">
  <option>Volvo</option>
  <option>Saab</option>
  <option>Mercedes</option>
  <option>Audi</option>
</SELECT>

you need to modify your selector to iterate over the <OPTION> tags, your selector was iterating over the <SELECT> tag


var inputName = mylist;
$(':input[name=' + inputName + '] option').each(function(i, selected)    {
        alert($(selected).text());
});
```

if you need in java script :

```
<form>
<select id="myselect">
<option value="cat">Option 1</option>
<option value="dog">Option 2</option>
<option value="bear">Option 3</option>
</select>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
var selectobject=document.getElementById("myselect")
for (var i=0; i<selectobject.length; i++){
alert(selectobject.options[i].text+" "+selectobject.options[i].value)
}

</script>
```

Comment: What does this have to do with the question? The OP showed his or her html. The  (possibly misguided) aim is to _create_ option elements with JS, not to iterate over existing ones.

Comment: "How to print dropdown values of a select tag using javascript?"..i guided him to print ...

Comment: he wants to print those element ...then only he/she use document.writeln('&ltoption value="chennai">');

Answer (score 0):

Your option tag should look like this:

```
<option value="chennai">Chennai</option>
```

The code snippet you posted would produce an invalid (unclosed) option tag.

Comment: Actually the html spec makes the closing </option> tag optional (though I prefer to include them). But including some text content as you did is definitely a good plan since that's what the user sees.

Comment: Well it worked ya...but when i place my code set inside body tag im displayed with an error stating script tag is placed in a wrong place....

Answer (score 0):

```
<select>
    <script >
        var list = [1,2,3];
        for(i in list){
            document.write("<option>"+list[i]+"</option>");
        }
    </script>
<select>

var list = ${cities}
```

Comment: Thanks! but i got to print the value also along with it! Moreover when use a "text" element in place of "select" it displays the values for me. but im not able to get them as dropdown values..thats the core problem....help me

Answer (score 0):

I will give you a demo.

```
 <?php
  $city=array('Chennai','Madurai','Dindigal');//array containing cities
  $count=1;
  echo "<select>";
  foreach($city as $value)
  {
    echo "<option value='city.$count'>".$value."</option>";
  }

  ?>
```

Hope you understands.You can also use the id of each  for other purposes in jsp

Comment: The question isn't tagged PHP.

Comment: @nnnnnn Ok,I suggested a solution for his problem in Php.

Comment: OK. I know you're trying to help, but I wouldn't think the OP would switch from JSP to PHP...

Comment: But when im placing my code set inside body tag im getting some error....like script is misplayed.....how to get rid of that?

Comment: @ user2002631  remove value attribute and check it.

Answer (score 0):

It's years since I've written anything in JSP and your question is lacking a bit in clarity but I think you're after something like this?

```
<%
 String[] cityArray={"Chennai","Madurai","Dindigal"};
%>
```

That's just a an array of cities as an example - I assume you have your own

Then, in your page code

```
<select>
<%
 int i=0;
 for(i=0;i<cityArray.length;i++)
 {
  out.print("<option>" + cityArray[i] + "</option>");
 }
%>
</select>
```

I've got nothing to test that with and the memory is a bit dim on jsp but is that what you mean?